# $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{a + \sin^2(\theta)} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a(a+1)}}$, for $a > 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I want to show that

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{a + \sin^2(\theta)} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a(a+1)}}$$

for $a > 0$.

I try several methods

1. Substitutions to rationalize
2. The famous $U = \tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$
3. Multiplying by conjugates

and other calculus techniques and still, I can not prove the equality.

Anyone can give me a hint of how should I begin to work this integral?

I'm very ashamed that I can not solve this problem.

Comment: I also try to replace $\sin^2(\theta)$ by $\frac{1 - cos(2\theta)}{2}$ but it didn't work neither. Maybe I should consider the exponential definition of sine ?

Comment: Try $\theta=\arctan(u)$

Comment: I found a stupid mistake in my computations using the substitution of $u = \tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$ and now I was able to solve the integral. However, @VivekKaushik answer was the fastest substitution for solving this integral that does not involve complex functions.

Comment: 1. Do not use `\displaystyle` in titles. They take up too much space, and you wouldn't want to be greedy. 2. Don't just put the problem in the title, it should be in the question itself. To borrow an analogy from another math.SE member: one does not start reading a book at the spine.

Comment: Loving the analogy. Sorry for bothering people with my displaystyle. I always use that because I hate small integrals without the displaystyle.

Comment: If you're curious why $\tan\theta$ was a more useful substitution than $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
Let $u=\tan(\theta),$ or $\theta=\arctan(u).$ Then the integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a+\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}} \frac{1}{1+u^2} \ du= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(a+1)u^2+a} \ du,$$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: I like this one, thanks.

Comment: I saw you did try the Weierstrass Substitution, which typically solves these kinds of trigonometric integrals.  Another interesting approach which is interesting is with complex variables. I've seen a lot of trigonometric integrals like this one be solved with the Residue Theorem on MSE.

Comment: In fact, this is a problem from the Residue Theorem of Conway's Complex Variable (2ed) book. I should use that method, but I realize that this is a real integral that I do not need to solve it using that method. I was trying to do it without complex integration.

Comment: No, that's not an error. Consider a right triangle with legs $u,1$ and hypotenuse $\sqrt{1+u^2}.$ Let $\theta$ be the angle opposite to the leg $u$ so that  $\tan(\theta)=u.$ Then $\sin(\theta)$ is $\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}.$ Squaring that gives $\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}.$

Answer (score 2):

**A complex analysis approach.**

Note that $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(t))$ with $t=2x$.  Moreover, let $z=e^{it}$, $dz=zi\,dt$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$, and, by using the Residue Theorem, we find
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{a+\sin^2(x)} &=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{a+\sin^2(x)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{dt}{(1+2a)-\cos(t)}\\
&=i\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z^2-2(1+2a)z+1}\\
\\&=2\pi i^2\mbox{Res}(f,z_2)=\frac{-2\pi}{2z_2-2(1+2a)}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a^2+a}}\end{align}$$
where the poles are $z_{1} = 2\sqrt{a^2+a}+1+2a$ and $z_{2} = -2\sqrt{a^2+a}+1+2a$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $\csc^2x$,

$$ \int \frac{\csc^2 \theta}{a \csc^2 \theta+1} \,d\theta$$

use $\csc^2\theta = \cot^2\theta+1$ and substitute $u\mapsto \cot \theta$,

$$ - \int \frac{1}{au^2 + a + 1}\,du $$

factor out $1/(a+1)$,

$$ \frac{-1}{a+1} \int \frac{1}{\frac{au^2}{a+1}+1}\,du $$

substitute $t\mapsto u\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+1}}$,

$$ -\frac 1 a \sqrt{\frac{a}{a+1}} \int \frac{1}{t^2+1}\, dt $$

use arctan derivative,

$$ -\frac 1 a \sqrt{\frac{a}{a+1}} \arctan(t) + c $$

and finally substitute back in to get,

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a(a+1)}} \cdot \arctan\left( \frac{\tan \theta}{\sqrt{a/(a+1)}}\right) + c $$

Now evaluate at the endpoints and you should get the RHS of your identity.

Comment: The t substitution looks wrong...I think you miss the u.

Comment: @RichardClare thanks! I've fixed the typo

Comment: Thank you for your solution is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

> \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{a +
> > \sin^2(\theta)}  &=  \frac{\pi}{2[a(a+1)]^\frac{1}{2}} \end{align}

\begin{align}
I=
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{a + \sin^2(\theta)} 
&= 
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{(\sqrt{a+1} + \cos\theta)
 (\sqrt{a+1} - \cos\theta} 
\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt{a+1}}
\left(
\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}
\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a+1} + \cos\theta}
+
\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2}
\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a+1} - \cos\theta}
\right)
.
\end{align}

Now we can use  a table integral

\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{u+v\cos x}
&=
\frac2{\sqrt{u^2-v^2}}
\arctan\left( \frac{(u-v)\tan\tfrac{x}2}{\sqrt{u^2-v^2}} \right)
,\quad u^2>v^2
\end{align}

for $u=\sqrt{a+1}$, $v=\pm 1$.

\begin{align}
I&=
\frac1{2\,u}
\frac2{\sqrt{u^2-1}}
\left(
\arctan\left(
\sqrt{\frac{u-1}{u+1}}\tan\tfrac\pi4
\right)
+
\arctan\left(
\sqrt{\frac{u+1}{u-1}}\tan\tfrac\pi4
\right)
\right)
,\\
&=
\frac1{u\,\sqrt{u^2-1}}
\left(
\arctan\left(
\sqrt{\frac{u-1}{u+1}}
\right)
+
\arctan\left(
\sqrt{\frac{u+1}{u-1}}
\right)
\right)
.
\end{align}

And since $\arctan x+\arctan \tfrac1x=\tfrac\pi2$ for $x>0$, we have

\begin{align}
I&=
\frac{\pi}{2\,\sqrt{a+1}\,\sqrt{a}}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Another method is as follows. Using $2\sin^{2}t = 1 - \cos 2t$ we can see that $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{a + \sin^{2}t} = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{2a + 1 - \cos 2t}$$ and putting $2t = z$ we get the integral as $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dz}{2a + 1 - \cos z}$$ which is equal to $$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{(2a + 1)^{2} - 1^{2}}} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a(a+1)}}$$ The above integral is a special case of the general formula $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{A + B\cos x} = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{A - B\cos x} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{A^{2} - B^{2}}}$$ which holds if $A > |B|$. The general formula can be established using the substitution $$(A + B\cos x)(A - B\cos y)= A^{2} - B^{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd\theta \over a + \sin^{2}\pars{\theta}} & =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta \over
a\sec^{2}\pars{\theta} + \tan^{2}\pars{\theta}} =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta \over
\pars{a + 1}\tan^{2}\pars{\theta} + a}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over a}\,\root{a \over a + 1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{%
\root{\pars{a + 1}/a}\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta \over
\bracks{\root{\pars{a + 1}/a}\tan\pars{\theta}}^{\,2} + 1}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x\ \equiv\ \root{\pars{a + 1}/a}\tan\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over \root{a\pars{a + 1}}}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}
_{\ds{=\ {\pi \over 2}}}\ =\
\bbx{\pi \over 2\,\bracks{a\pars{a + 1}}^{1/2}}
\end{align}