# $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\frac{dx}{a+\sin^2(x)}}$ for $|a|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

Evaluate: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\frac{dx}{a+\sin^2(x)}}$$ for $|a|>1$

Note: This integral is to be solved using complex analysis (Calculus of Residues)

Comment: WA gives the following answer: $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\pi 
   (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{\arg (a)-\arg (a+1)+\pi }{2
   \pi }\right\rfloor }}{2 \sqrt{a}
   \sqrt{a+1}},\Re\left(\cos ^{-1}(2 a+1)\right)>\pi
   \lor \Re\left(\cos ^{-1}(2 a+1)\right)<0\lor \cos
   ^{-1}(2 a+1)\notin \mathbb{R}\right]$$

Comment: @alFeraas You will find the evaluation by using complex analysis here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3429398/299698

Comment: how is that $cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$?

Comment: and how is $a+sin^2(x) = (1+2a) - cos(x)$

Comment: also,how that the interval become from $0$ to $2\pi$? by multiplying by 1/2 not 1/4?

Comment: All good now. Thanks

Comment: @alFeraas It's nice that you appreciate my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3429398/299698